# How do I tell Windows to prefer the find.exe from UnxUtils instead of Windows's find?

Tags: windows, windows-7

I installed UnxUtils on Windows 7. But when I try to use `find` in cmd.exe, Windows's find.exe in system32/ is the one that gets invoked. How do I tell Windows to prefer the find.exe from UnxUtils instead of Windows's find?

Comment: Make sure it is located first via `%PATH%`. That is, the UnxUtils bin path should appear first.

Comment: Future questions like this might be better suited to superuser.com. Specifically, you're asking how to configure or optimize the computer, you're not writing new programs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by adding a reference to the executable file to your "Path" system variable.

1) Right click on "Computer" from the Start Menu.

2) Select "Properties"

3) Click "Advanced System Settings"

4) Click "Environment Variables"

5) Select the "Path" System Variable

6) Click "Edit"

7) Add the path to the UnxUtils bin directory to the begining of your path:

ie: **C:\UnxUtils\bin;** C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows... 
**(DON'T COPY AND PASTE THIS)**

8) Ok and Exit out of the Prompts.

Now in new and subsequent command prompts UnxUtils executables should be picked up first.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think its good idea to put anything of system32 in your global PATH.  In a specific shell environment (dot-file or powershell profile) would be fine, but not user-level or computer-level global path.

Another option is to use a batch file or shell alias.  Alias the *nx `find` to `f`.  This is `sal` in powershell, `doskey` in DOS/CMD.  No matter the shell, aliases will resolve ahead of PATH expansion.

If you're using stuff like UnxUtils I suggest you check out powershell profile.ps1.  Or create an equivalent 'startup' script in your favorite shell, even CMD.exe.

C:\Users\bob\Documents\WindowsPowershell\profile.ps1

```
sal f C:\UnxUtils\bin\find.exe             # terse
Set-Alias find2 C:\UnxUtils\bin\find.exe   # verbose
```